# What's the average weight of a professional's Cue stick?

Tags: equipment, pool, snooker

As I have observed my Cue action is better with a heavier stick but I kind of feel good with a relatively lighter one.

What's the average weight of a professional's Cue stick as I'm in early stages of the game and want to go with one type.

Comment: Some like a heavier cue for breaking.  The heavier the better.  On top of that, for breaking they may also go for a bigger tip if generally using a snooker cue for mid frame playing

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_stick#Snooker):

> Snooker cue weights vary between 16 and 18 oz. While a lighter cue is
>   usually for beginners to develop correct technique when starting out,
>   some professional snooker players use lighter cues (15 - 16 1/2 oz.)

Based on this information, weight of the cue stick is very preferential, but it would be safe to consider the average weight of a professional's cue stick to be between 15-18 ounces.

Answer (score 0):

In American pool, the most common weights of a cue are 18 to 21 ounces.  However, you can go lighter or heavier.

Quality pool cues have a hollow part in the butt of the cue, typically under the bumper, where weights can be added or removed.  This allows you to change the weight of your cue, without buying a new one.